# why there have 15px\-15px in row and col-XX-n, why not use 0 on row or col-XX-n directly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I notice some code in BootStrap, as follow:

```
.row{
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
}
.col-XX-n{
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

I'm confused it. Because I think the negative **-15** and **15** equal **zero** and why not write **0** to instead it?

Comment: What about the second column?

Comment: @SLaks col-xs-12, col-xs-9, col-lg-3,etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of this padding is to add 15 pixels of space between each column in a row.

The negative margin removes unwanted space from before the first column.

Comment: sorry, I update my question. I know the function about the row and column , just confused by the -15\15. Because I think -15\15 is excess, but Bootstrap use it, there is something meaning point.

Comment: @ToddMark: Read my answer more carefully.  The point is for the columns after the first one.